# Screen Positioning Tool

Tags: screen

Quick question is there a screen positioning tool for Ubuntu, that can tell the user exactly where the mouse located on the screen? (Perhaps something similar to [Cursor Position](http://download.cnet.com/Cursor-Position/3000-2383_4-75449858.html) for Winodws)

Comment: from command line: install `xdotool` (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`), run the command: `xdotool  getmouselocation`. It outputs like:  `x:564 y:568 screen:0 window:81789111`. Not sure if that is what you are looking for? Please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `xdotool`. The package has a `getmouselocation` tool to give the coordinates of the mouse.

Install `xdotool`, with the following cmd:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

To get the location of the mouse, use:

```
 xdotool getmouselocation
```

And also try:

```
watch xdotool getmouselocation
```